# How to check a DWForms field for spaces?

Tags: python, flask

I'm using Python3.6 with Flask and WTForms. I have several form validations that work, but the one that checks the username for spaces isn't working. Do I need to use re to do regex instead?

```
def validate_username(self, username):
    if username.data != current_user.username:
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
        if ' ' in username.data == True:
            raise ValidationError("Username may not contain a space.")
        if user:
            raise ValidationError('That username is taken by a 
                different user. Please choose another.')
```

Comment: if (' ' in data) == True: try this may be works

Comment: username.data is the variable where the string is stored. Adding the () did not change the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to cast the search as a raw string. The following code is the solution.

```
if (r' 'in username.data):
    raise ValidationError('Username cannot contain spaces.')
```